# How to delete rows based on OR and AND conditions in r

Tags: r

I want to delete rows that have ID=3 but GENDER not equal to "F".

```
df<-data_frame(ID=c(2,3,3,3,3,5,6,7,8,9),GENDER=c("M","M","F","F","F","M","F","F","M","F"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create a logical expression in `filter` and negate (`!`) the whole to remove those rows

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
       filter(!(ID == 3 & GENDER != "F"))
```

---

or the same with `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df, !(ID == 3 & GENDER != "F"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to phrase the condition is to select rows where `ID` not equal to 3 or `GENDER = 'F'`.

```
subset(df, ID != 3 | GENDER == 'F')

#    ID GENDER
#  <dbl> <chr> 
#1     2 M     
#2     3 F     
#3     3 F     
#4     3 F     
#5     5 M     
#6     6 F     
#7     7 F     
#8     8 M     
#9     9 F
```

and with `dplyr` `filter` :

```
dplyr::filter(df, ID != 3 | GENDER == 'F')
```